# problem on connecting devices in eagle

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

i'm still a biginner in using eagle .... well everything is almost fine but i keep having this error .... although i cheked a 100 time

> Only INPUT pins on net 25
>
> Only INPUT pins on net RXCAN
>
> Only INPUT pins on net RXCAN

[image]

Please can some one help me .... it's urgent

Comment: We can't see what else is on those nets.

Comment: It is probably because whoever made the Arduino symbol you are presumably using (guessing from your yellow text) set the wrong direction of the pin. If you open the symbol and change the direction of the pin to inout I think it is then that will get rid of the warnings. Also if you use the 'show' tool it will verify that the nets are connected as intended.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i highlited the problems

Comment: @TomCarpenter ok i will try it then i will answer you :)

Comment: @TomCarpenter no it's not working but anyway i'm sur that it's connected

Comment: If RXCAN connects pin 2 (RXCAN) of U$6 to pin 4 (RXD) of U$2, you do probably have two inputs connected together - I'd expect RXCAN to connect to TXD, or TXCAN to connect to RXD.

Answer (score 2):

These errors occur when the symbol for a component has its leads marked as 'in" in the symbol view in the Eagle libraries.  Then the other end should be either "out" or "io" (I believe the latter is the default.)  Other choices for pins are nc, oc, pwr, hiz and a couple others.  So you should check pin 25 of the Arduino symbol that it is shown as either "out" or "io" (if you click on the pin in the symbol view, and select Properties, it will show this.)

As far as the RX leads go, it appears you have one RX lead tied to another (RXCAN to RXD).  These would normally both be inputs.

Usually UART leads are cross-connected, so RXCAN would be connected to TXD, and TXCAN would be connected to RXD.  *Occasionally* RX is an output from a device, and TX is an input, so that RX is connected to RX and TX is connected to TX, but this is very rare. I don't think that's the situation here as I checked the datasheet for the MCP2515 and TXCAN is shown as an output and RXCAN is an input.